# XCode 4.6 - Debugging EXC_BAD_ACCESS without a stack trace

Tags: c++, xcode, exc-bad-access, juce

I already searched the web for a while but it appears my problem is very rare:

I'm programming a Audio Unit Plugin with JUCE in C++.
When I run it in a host, the host crashes. When I attach the XCode debugger to the hoist before loading my plugin, it points me to the following:

```
 error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file
```

If I type "bt" into the debug console, it says:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x00000000, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)
frame #0: 0x00000000
```

I don't get a stack trace, making it impossible to find the source of the bug. It would help a lot to see, what was executed right before the bad access happened, but I can't figure out how.

I can set a breakpoint somewhere in the program and from there slowly make my way through the code until I reach the crash. I did this and eventually the execution leaves my source code and I get the assembly lines. I can see it jumping out of a lot of calls with the "ret" command. Eventually on one "ret" command, the crash occurs.

The assembly code is from the host that runs my plugin. But the crash appears on different types of host so I'm pretty sure, its a fault on my side. Any ideas?

Thank you!